# Close a specific window using macos terminal in another app

Tags: macos, terminal

I can already close an entire application using terminal but when it comes to closing a specific window in, say, textedit I cannot do it.  Why can I open specific files using terminal but now also close them?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find out how to do it but here is a workaround using applescript from a python program:

```
os.system(f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "TextEdit" to close (every window whose name is "allen_grammar.txt")' ''')
```